# How can I unit test a gluon mobile application?

Tags: gluon-mobile

I have created a "Gluon Mobile - Multi View Project with FXML" using IntelliJ. Now I would like to write junit tests for code residing in the main directory, additionally I would like to write unit tests for platform specific code residing in the android, desktop and ios folders.

I managed to write unit tests for the main code by adding a src/test/java folder. Those tests get automatically executed when building the project.

But how can I add platform specific unit tests and integration tests? What do I have to add to build.gradle to make the jfxmobile-plugin know and execute those tests?

Any help is very much appreciated.